# Extend behaviour from model in shared code folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `common` folder inside my project directory with some classes that we are sharing between projects (using other techniques as engines is not an option for us at this point). We have the project structure 'replicated' inside this folder, so we have some paths like `common/app/models`, `common/lib` and so on). To load all the models we are using:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(
  #{config.root}/common/app/models
  #{config.root}/lib
)
```

But now I need to extend in some way the behaviour of one on the classes in the `common/app/models` folder.

My first option was create a new `ExtendedModel` in the regular application models folder, inherit from `SharedModel`, migrate the records to the new model, and then place something like `ExtendedModel = SharedModel` inside an initializer. It will work, but it seems a little tricky.

My second choice was to creating a new model in the application models folder with the same name `SharedModel` and the different method, but Rails seems to be ignoring this model and it's using only the `SharedModel`.

Any ideas would be appreciated :)

Comment: Ruby allows you to extend classes dynamically, so there should be no issue with this. So, what I suggest, is to go into the command line (rails c) load your model extension definition, and check if  a new instance will have this new method.

Comment: that sounds overly complicated to me. additionally, what does the autoloading part has to do with this? isn't all about inheritance and mixins?

Comment: @tomsoft I've already tried this, and the method is not loaded. I've found a workaround to this, I'll answer my question.

Comment: @phoet I need this because I'm using a different models directory.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I arrived to some kind of solution, although I can't consider it a very satisfying one :(.

I added a `shared_model.rb` file in `app/models` with the following content:

```
SharedModel.class_eval do
  def overriden_method
    puts 'hi!'
  end
end
```

And then I added an initializer with the content:

```
load('app/models/shared_model.rb').
```

I'm doing more tests but seems to be working.

Comment: how is this better than any other monkey-patching? why are you loading the file instead of putting it into some folder that gets autoloaded? you will brake class loading with this.

Comment: @phoet Because it works, and avoids to put all the code into an initializer. Placing the class with the overridden behaviour in the app/models folder is not working, at least for me. What's exactly your proposal? :)